# Получить значение из модального окна

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2, modal

**Задача:** *через элемент списка "Добавить компанию ...", сперва спросить наименование, после создать ее и выбрать в списке.*

Я реализовал ее следующим образом (ниже ссылка на ролик):
https://www.screencast.com/t/azx2VZ0Zi

Здесь для ввода значения использую prompt(), а нужно сделать красивое модальное окно. Как это сделать?

Выпадающий список реализован через библиотеку jq select2. Собственно клик по элементу списка уже генерирует событие на чтение свойств компании, в случае клика по "Добавить компанию ..."  к.о. нужно вызвать модальное окно, принять значение и добавить новый элемент списка до его закрытия.

За основу я взял bootstrap модальное окно, настроил под себя:

```
<div class="modal fade deal-modal-add-name-company" data-id="">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Введите имя компании</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

                <div class="form-group row-property">
                    <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Название:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input name="name" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="..." value="" maxlength="50">
                    </div>
                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-add-name-company">Сохранить</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ниже код js. В обработчике select2:select я пробую вызвать модальное окно:

```
$(".deal-modal-add-name-company").modal("show");
```

но как перехватить введенные значения после нажатия кнопки "Сохранить"?

Код js:

```
    doCompanyNameSelect: function ($el) {
    var self = this;
    var value = +$el.val();

    if ($el.closest(".template").length > 0)
        return;

    var selectedCompanies = $(".company[data-id]").map(function () {
        return +$(this).attr("data-id")
    }).toArray();

    $el.find("option").prop("disabled", false).each(function (i, item) {
        var $item = $(item);
        var id = +$item.attr("value");
        if (selectedCompanies.indexOf(id) > -1 && id > 0 && id != value)
            $item.prop("disabled", true);
    });

    if ($el.hasClass("select2-hidden-accessible")) {
        $el.select2("destroy").off("select2:select");
    }

    $el.select2({
        tags: true,
        width: '100%',
        placeholder: "Выбирите компанию...",
        allowClear: true,
        createTag: function (params) {
            return {
                id: params.term,
                text: params.term,
                newOption: true
            }
        },
        templateResult: function (data) {
            var $result = $("<span></span>");

            $result.text(data.text);

            if (data.newOption) {
                $result.append(" <em>(новая компания)</em>");
            }

            return $result;
        },
    })
        .on("select2:select", function (e) {
            var el = $(this);
            if (el.val() === "newCompany") {
                var newval = prompt("Введите имя компании: ");
                $(".deal-modal-add-name-company").modal("show");
                if (newval !== null) {
                    el.append('<option>' + newval + '</option>')
                        .val(newval);
                }
            }

            self.showSaveControls();

            var id = +e.params.data.id;
            if (isNaN(id))
                id = -1;
            var text = e.params.data.text;

            var $company = $el.closest(".company");
            $company.attr("data-id", id);

            if (id > 0) {
                $el.prop("disabled", true);

                self.fillCompanyInfo($company, id, function () {
                    $el.prop("disabled", false);

                    $(".company-name").not($el).each(function () {
                        self.doCompanyNameSelect($(this));
                    });
                });

            } else {
                self.clearCompanyInfo($company);

                $(".company-name").not($el).each(function () {
                    self.doCompanyNameSelect($(this));
                });
            }
        });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно отловить событие клика по кнопке сохранить, затем найти инпут с названием и взять его значение.

```
$('.btn-add-name-company').on('click', function () {
  var name = $('.modal').find('inpit[name="name"]').val();
  //Делайте с ним то, что нужно
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне помог совет @fox-f.
Я вызвал модальное окно в обработчике события выбора элемента списка, здесь:

```
    .on("select2:select", function (e) {
    if ($el.val() === "newCompany") {
    $(".deal-modal-add-name-company .alert-danger").addClass("hide");
    $(".deal-modal-add-name-company").modal("show");
```

и добавил обработчик для кнопки "Сохранить":

```
    $(".btn-add-name-company").on("click", function (e) {
        var $input = $(".deal-modal-add-name-company").find("input");
        var val = $input.val();

        if (val !== "") {
            $("select.company-name.form-control.select2-hidden-accessible").append('<option>' + val + '</option>').val(val);
            $(".deal-modal-add-name-company").modal("hide");
        }
        else
        {
            var msg = $(".deal-modal-add-name-company .alert-danger");
            msg.removeClass("hide");
        }
    });
```